# How to find my.cnf file for plesk server?

Tags: plesk

I am using plesk server with multiple sites running. I want to set `ft_min_word_len=3` for full text search. I have found that I have to change the option file but problem is that I am not being able to find out the file my.cnf. I have come to know that this file is found either in `/etc/` or `/home/mydir/` but do not know how and where to check this file.

Answer (score 4):

You can use nice Unix tools such as Locate ou Find to find that file.

To use the locate tool, first generate the database :

> updatedb

Then search for the file

> locate my.cnf

Answer (score 1):

Or, to find it faster then messing with locate (the DB should actually be automatically kept fairly up to date) try this:

```
find /etc -name my.cnf
find ~ -name my.cnf
```

One of those should print a line showing where my.cnf is.

Answer (score 0):

Run "ps -eF" to see the command line being passed to the mysql process. If it's a non-standard config file it should appear there. If it isn't a listed option it will use the compile time default for mysql, which is normally dependent on the OS mysql package (rpm etc.) rather than plesk.

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -name my.cnf -type f -print
```

should do it, but it might run slow.

Answer (score 0):

The path is: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`